# Trying to remove the first character of a word and placing it at the end

Tags: c, localization, apache-pig

first time posting to this site.
I'm trying to write a pig latin translating program and am having difficulty in removing the first character of each word in a string and appending it to the end of the word. If anyone could give me any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. However I am trying not to change what I already have too much. As far as string functions go I am limited to using strcpy, strcmp, strlen, and strtok as I am but a stumped student in a comprehensive course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main (void)
{
 char sentence[81]; /* holds input string */
 char *platin;   /* will point to each word */

 printf ("This program translate the words in your sentence.\n");
 printf ("Type end to finish.\n");

 do  /* for each sentence */
    {
     printf ("\n\nType a sentence until 'stop': \n ");
     gets (sentence);

        platin = strtok (sentence, " ");
     while (platin != NULL)  /*Moves translator from word to word */
            {

                if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", *platin)) /*Checks for vowels */
                    {

                    printf(" %sway ", platin);
                    }

                else if (strchr("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ",*platin))
                    {
                    printf(" %say", platin);    
                    }




             platin = strtok(NULL, " ");



             }
 } while (strcmp(sentence, "stop") != 0 );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't find a space, the word isn't finish. So copy the world into a buffer, and then once you found a space, switch the letters :

```
char[1024] wordBuff;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {
    if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
        char tmpC = wordBuff[j-1];   //
        wordBuff[j-1] = wordBuff[0]; //  switch the letters
        wordBuff[0] = tmpC;          //
        wordBuff[j] = '\0';          //  end of word
        printf("%s\n", wordBuff);
        j = 0;
    }
    else
        wordBuff[j++] = sentence[i]; // fill wordBuff with word's char
}
```